# Toggle between checked and unchecked from backend in type script

Tags: typescript, checkbox, aurelia

I have an HTML component for check box named `is_enabled` when I add a data to form I had checked it, and when I try to edit the same if I unchecked the checkbox, the value remains checked. How can I edit a check box value? I have tried the following code

```
is_enabled: this.is_enabled ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: Did you try connecting it to `ngModel`?

Comment: also, include code that you have already tried.